# What does a bare < do?

Tags: bash

`bash` does not seem to complain if you run a command like

```
$ < some-file-that-exists
```

Nothing seems to happen.

You could also use

```
$ <<<"any string"
```

and even process substitution.

So what exactly does this do, and why is it allowed.  Could it be useful for anything?

Comment: BTW: For the great ZSH, "< foobar" is the same as "less foobar", as your redirect foobar to the shell. I think this is a quite intuitive behavior. A bare `<` will give you an error (`zsh: parse error near \`\n'`) as no argument is given.

Comment: @math you will get a similar error in `bash`, but that is interesting about `less`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`<` sets up redirection for a command that can occur before or after the redirection instructions.  I.e.

```
$ < file wc
```

works as well as

```
$ wc < file
```

But if you don't give a command, bash sets up the redirection and doesn't do anything else.  For input redirection, this amounts to what you saw, nothing, if the file exists and is readable.  If the file does not exist or is not readable bash will signal an error.  For output redirection, the output file will be created if it does not exist.  Any existing  output file will be truncated if `>` is used; no truncation if `>>` is used.

Comment: in other words they are a concise exists and create

Comment: @Kyle Jones I think you mismatched the two operators in the last sentence.

Comment: @Puddingfox Thanks.  I've edited the run-on sentence at the end to clarify.

Comment: Is there any reason to use `< file wc` vs. `wc < file`?

Comment: @tandu It comes in handy when using interactive shells.  Say you have a command that uses redirection and you want to repeat it with a different last argument.  If the redirection is at the beginning of the line, it's easy to type control-P and then edit the last argument without having to skip over the "< foo > bar 2>&1" language as you would if it were at the end.  Beyond that, I've found no use for it.

Comment: @KyleJones history expansion sounds like it would obviate that too :/

Answer (score 5):

< reads from stdin by default, or a file. your expression does not do anything with the input because you did not do anyting after reading.

if you do  < some-file-that-exists > outputfile at the end, then you will see that you have just read in the content of the first file and wrote it to the second file.

<<< is here doc format, so it reads from a string instead from a file. cat <<<"any string" to see what you have read.

Comment: for future reference, please edit your answer to add detail instead of adding a comment

Comment: "if you do < some-file-that-exists > outputfile at the end then you will see that you have just read in the content of the first file and wrote it to the second file."  This is wrong; without a command the output file will be truncated to zero bytes.